# On Japanese StackOverflow some of the badge text and descriptions are in English

Tags: 討議, 完了

Go to the [Japanese StackOverflow badges page](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges).

While most badges and descriptions are in Japanese, some badges and some badge descriptions are in English.

Here's one example where just the description needs localization

[image: Example 1]

and here's a few where the badges themselves also need localization

[image: Example 2]

Answer (score 1):

この投稿はmeta.seより投稿されたものですので、英語でした。

完了済みです。

Comment: Explainerもコピー編集者も直っていないように見えますが・・・。

Comment: @unarist 前に直したと思いました。すみません！確認してみます。

Comment: @unarist [バッジページ](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)では、全部は日本語になっていますが、そうではないですか？

Comment: そのページで、`Explainer` `Refiner` `Illuminator`のラベルと説明、`ベータ` `コピー編集者` の説明が英語のままに見えます。rev2015.4.1.2436です。

Comment: @jmac は私はまだ、上記の1を見ている。悪い日本人は、私は英語だ。

Comment: @unarist 開発者と確認中です。[Transifex上](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40289627?comment=%2F142%2F)では翻訳済みですが、おしゃっている通りに適用していないらしいです。

Comment: @unarist キャッシュの問題でした。現在は１つの文書以外、日本語になっています。